# Deserialization without decorators

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, deserialization, decorator

I have simple class with several members, let say `String name` and `list<String> friends`. After creation of an instance of the class, I want to serialize the object and deserialize it back:

```
        //serialize
        myClass mine = new myClass();
        mine.name = "Peter";
        var xmls = new XmlSerializer(typeof(myClass));

        using (System.IO.FileStream file = System.IO.File.Create(path))
        {
            xmls.Serialize(file, mine);
        }

        //deserialize
        var xmls = new XmlSerializer(typeof(myClass));
        using (System.IO.FileStream file = System.IO.File.Open(path, System.IO.FileMode.Open))
        {
            myClass mine = (myClass) xmls.Deserialize(file);
            Console.writeline(mine.name);
        }
```

Deserialization process works well, which surprise me a bit, since I was expecting that I need the decorators for the XML elements. What is the hack behind? Is this because I do not use another variables in my class? When the members should be marked for deserialization with decorators like `[XmlElement("Name")]`?

Thank you!

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. Did you look at the xml, and is there something about it that's not right?

Comment: Everything is correct. Im just wondering how does XML deserializer know names of variables,I was about that  decorators are there for this purpose. I was playing with the C# long time ago and I remember that I had to put the decorators in order to parse "deserialize" XML correctly, variable names was just not enough.

Comment: The properties have to be public to be able to serialize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure about previous versions, but since .Net Framework 4.5 the [XmlSerializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer?view=netframework-4.7.2) uses this attribute (`XmlElementAttribute`) to control xml serialization. It's not required for the de/serialization process.

> **By default, an XML element name is determined by the class or member name**. In a simple class named Book, a field named ISBN will produce an XML element tag .

<sup>Source: [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/controlling-xml-serialization-using-attributes)</sup>

Often the [**`XmlElement` attribute**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2) is used when you want to give an alternative name for a member in your class (or to the class itself) that represents that element in xml format.

For example, this class:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

as you've used it:

```
var mine = new MyClass();
mine.Name = "Peter";
...
xmls.Serialize(file, mine);
```

should be serialized as

```
<MyClass>
    <Name>Peter</Name>
</MyClass>
```

Bu you can controle the xml output with the `XmlElementAttribute` giving another name to the property in xml format. Like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    [XmlElement("UserName")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then the output should be like:

```
<MyClass>
    <UserName>Peter</UserName>
</MyClass>
```

There are other attributes that help to control the xml de/serialization as `DefaultValue` and `XmlIgnore` that may be pretty useful. You can read more about it in the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/attributes-that-control-xml-serialization).

I hope it helps.